# Trying to call from Postman fails but works from app

Tags: c#, json, api, postman

I am trying to call a C# api endpoint from Postman. I'm simplifying the code from a working one:

```
url: https://localhost:44302/api/MyControllerName/MyMethodName
Method: Post
Headers: 
    Content-Type: application/json
    Accept: application/json
    Body: {"ids": "1234asdfasdfasdf3e"}
```

and my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/MyControllerName/MyMethodName")]
    public async Task PostNewIds([FromBody] string ids)
    { // <-- breakpoint here is never hit
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ids);
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
    }
```

but I am getting this error in VS and can't reach the breakpoint set at the open curly bracket

```
{"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace? Also, shouldn't it be deserialize rather than serialize?

Comment: Try to set encoding manually: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` (or any other encoding, that your API can understand.

Comment: are you receiving `ids` values in method while call it from Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `PostNewIds` action, you are deserializing request body as `string` parameter, so your `ids == @"{""ids"":""1234asdfasdfasdf3e""}"`. If you need to get `ids` value from request, you may add a model:

```
public class MyMethodNameModel
{
    public string Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use this model within your action:

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/MyControllerName/MyMethodName")]
public async Task PostNewIds([FromBody] MyMethodNameModel model)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(model.Ids);
}
```

**OR** if you wish, you may use @Hasan suggestion and deserialize "by-hands":

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/MyControllerName/MyMethodName")]
public async Task PostNewIds([FromBody] string body)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ids) as JObject;
    var val = obj["ids"] as JValue;
    Debug.WriteLine(val.Value);
}
```

Comment: The answer of using a model class object would do enough, but even better if I could pass in the string directly without containing it inside the object.